# Fortran: referring to an array/data block with a string variable

Tags: variables, fortran

It isn't easy to describe my question, so I'll do it with an example. Say I have two data blocks, and one Character array (string):

```
DATA Foo1/ 0 1 2 3 /
DATA Foo2/ 4 5 6 7 /
CHARACTER*4 FOO
```

`FOO` is an input here and can contain one of the two strings `"Foo1"` or `"Foo2"`. 
I would very much like to be able to write something like: `FOO(2)`, by which I mean: Get me the second element of the data block to which the variable `FOO` refers to. For example, if `FOO="Foo2"`, then in my fantasy world: `FOO(2) = 5`

However, `FOO` is just a string, not the name of an array/data block.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i believe you are describing whats called a dictionary in other languages (eg python).

Answer (score 0):

There may be the pointer option:

```
integer, target, dimension(4) :: Foo1, Foo2
data Foo1/0, 1, 2, 3/
data Foo2/4, 5, 6, 7/
integer, pointer, dimension(:) :: foo_ptr
character(4) foo

...

if (foo.eq.'Foo1') then
  foo_ptr => Foo1
else  ! Perhaps more condition checking
  foo_ptr => Foo2
end if

print*, foo_ptr(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or via a user-defined type:

```
program Match

type Foo_type
   character (len=4) :: name
   integer, dimension (1:4) :: values
end type Foo_type

type (Foo_type), dimension (:), allocatable :: Foo

integer :: i, Match_i
character (len=4) :: MatchName

allocate ( Foo (2) )

!  initialize by some means...
Foo (1) % name = "Foo1"
Foo (2) % name = "Foo2"
Foo (1) % values = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
Foo (2) % values = [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ]

write (*, '("Input name: ")', advance="no")
read (*, '(A)' )  MatchName

Match_i = 0
MatchLoop: do i=1, size (Foo)
   if ( Foo (i) % name == MatchName ) then
      Match_i = i
      exit MatchLoop
   end if
end do MatchLoop

!  handle Match_i = 0

write (*, *) Foo (Match_i) % values (2)

end program Match
```